# Users on one VLAN cannot access multicast resources

Tags: routing, vlan, multicast

[image]Feel like I'm getting closer to fixing my issue...

This is the simplified version of the multicast...

-No RPF Failure
-pim sparse mode on all interfaces
-multicast routing enabled

I forced a group join and pinged the multicast group from the receiving router and seen the packets being forwarded.
Still the users are not seeing feeds.

One thing I did notice before I had to cut out for the day that throws a red flag.

On the rendezvous Point looking through the logs there are ALOT of

```
%PIM-1-INVALID_RP_REG: Received Register from router x.x.x.x for group 237.0.0.1, 1.2.3.4 not willing to be RP
```

Comment: Did you configure multicast routing?

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the configurations. Also, you should not be using any multicast group `237.0.0.1` because it is in the reserved range of `235.0.0.0` to `238.255.255.255`. You should use something in the Organization-Local Scope of `239.0.0.0/8`.

Answer (score 1):

Multicast, like broadcast, is normally confined to one VLAN. You must configure your network to route multicast, and multicast routing is very different than unicast routing. Multicast needs several protocols (IGMP, PIM etc.) in order to properly route multicast to only those networks where multicast is wanted.

Cisco has a diagram of the multicast protocols:

[image]

---

You have not included a network diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations, so we cannot help you with more information.